# Random Shuffle Listing in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, list, random, shuffle

I'm in a little bit of a pickle. I have this script of an array that shows a listing of items. Now the thing is I only want this list to have five items shown out of ten and also shuffled, so you cant have the same list every time you start a new game. I was thinking if there should be a Random.Range implemented but I dont know where. Please Help and Thanks. Heres the script: `

```
public class RayCasting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float pickupDistance;
    public List<Item> items;


    #region Unity
    void Start ()
    {
        Screen.lockCursor = true;
    }
    void Update ()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, pickupDistance))
        {
            foreach(Item item in items)
            {

                if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
                    if (item.gameObject.Equals(hit.collider.gameObject))
                {
                    numItemsCollected++;
                    item.Collect();
                    break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {

        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(130,400,100,100));
        {
            GUILayout.BeginVertical();
            {
        if (numItemsCollected < items.Count)
        {
            foreach (Item item in items)

                        GUILayout.Label(string.Format("[{0}] {1}", item.Collected ? "X" : " ", item.name));
        }
        else
        {
            GUILayout.Label("You Win!");
        }
            }
            GUILayout.EndVertical();
    }
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private
    private int numItemsCollected;
    #endregion
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public string name;
    public GameObject gameObject;

    public bool Collected { get; private set; }

    public void Collect()
    {
        Collected = true;
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: If you want to really shuffle it, follow the Fisher-Yates algorithm, you can find it on Wiki. If you just want some randomness, do a `OrderBy` with `Random.Next` or `new Guid`. There's also about 15 duplicates of the exact same question, pick one.

Comment: I am still kind of new to this, and still learning the ropes, so is it alright if you can elaborate on this, and I pretty much searched and I have not found anything with an array and a list being shuffled within an array.

Answer (score 1):

To get a random 5 items from your 10 item list you can use:

```
List<Items> AllItems = new List<Items>();

List<Items> RandomItems = new List<Items>();

Random random = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    RandomItems.Add(AllItems[random.Next(0, AllItems.Count + 1)]);
}
```

The AllItems list contains your 10 items.

After the loop you will have 5 random items inside the RandomItems list.

Comment: so should I replace my 

public List<Item> items;

with your

List<Items> AllItems = new List<Items>();

Comment: Your items list can stay the same. You just need to populate it with the 5 random items you want. So in my example you would replace RandomItems with your items list.

Comment: random.Next...Next isnt complying, its saying its not a variable.

Comment: You have to create an instance of the Random class available inside the System; library. Unity3D built in Random class only contains static methods, and does not contain a Next method. So on top of your code underneath the using UnityEngine; add the line: using System; Once you add that replace my line of code: Random random = new Random(); with System.Random random = new System.Random();

Comment: Once Input using Systems; it cancelled out Random and have not changed Next...am I suppose to just put uning Systems; or is there more to it?

Comment: Im getting these errors:
Assets/RayCasting.cs(11,14): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Items' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?....

Assets/RayCasting.cs(15,9): error CS0104: `Random' is an ambiguous reference between `UnityEngine.Random' and `System.Random'

Comment: Im sorry I completely looked over what you said about System.Random random = new System.Random()

Comment: Ok I got everything down but Im still running into this error Assets/RayCasting.cs(11,14): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Items' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, this is my solution for shuffle any kind of List

```
public class Ext : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(List<T> _list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _list.Count; i++)
        {
            T temp = _list[i];
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(i, _list.Count);
            _list[i] = _list[randomIndex];
            _list[randomIndex] = temp;
        }

        return _list;
    }
}
```

With your example it should work like this:

```
AllItems = Ext.Shuffle<Items>(AllItems);
Debug.Log(AllItems[0]); // Will be always random Item
```

If you need 5 random Items, you can just call

```
Debug.Log(AllItems[0]); // Random Item
Debug.Log(AllItems[1]); // Random Item
Debug.Log(AllItems[2]); // Random Item
Debug.Log(AllItems[3]); // Random Item
Debug.Log(AllItems[4]); // Random Item
```